# Zinnia entry summary

Tags: django, templates, blogs, zinnia

I'm currently building a blogging site with Django / Zinnia (latest version), and am having some trouble with controlling the entries summary.

Two questions:

- How can I display an entry summary?  (in a sidebar) I cannot find template tags or parameters that control that specific point.
- How can I control the length of the summary? (e.g. max 130 characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zinnia's `Entry` model has an `excerpt` attribute, if thats what you mean my `summary`.

https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/blob/master/zinnia/models_bases/entry.py#L352

You'll need to override `entry-detail` template if you want to add the `summary` to `sidebar` for a blog entry.

http://docs.django-blog-zinnia.com/en/develop/how-to/customize_look_and_feel.html#templates-for-entry-detail

And to limit characters for `excerpt` you can extend the `entry` model

http://docs.django-blog-zinnia.com/en/develop/how-to/extending_entry_model.html

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for your answer! I didn't find that exerpt attribute :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I achieved to find a very simple and elegant answer. So simple that I first want to apoligize being realtively new to Django and Zinnia...

Well, the `Entry` model contains all we need for this solution:

- `excerpt` returns the beggining of the article, without formatting.
- `html_preview` returns the same thing, but formatted in HTML.

Next, in the template tags of the customized Zinnia templates (`entry-detail.html` or another, `entry_popular.html` and `entry_popular.html` in my case), you can simply limit the returned string lenght with the `slice` template tag command:

`{{ entry.excerpt|slice:"120" }}`

It works very well in my sidebar for displaying popular, recent and featured articles and should work for many purposes too. Hope this helps! :-)